# Amazon S3 Bucket configuration issue in node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I am trying to configure Amazon S3 bucket but getting some bucket error. The error message
is :
case 'undefined': throw new Error('bucket is required')
^
Error: bucket is required

```
at new S3Storage (/Users/node_modules/multer-s3/index.js:94:29)
at module.exports (/Users/node_modules/multer-s3/index.js:214:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/app/middlewares/fileUploader.js:52:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
```

My fileUploader code is as follows. And the bucket credentials are store in ENV file.

```
      case "development":
        accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEVELOPMENT;
        accessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEVELOPMENT;
        bucketName = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_DEVELOPMENT;
        bucketFolder="staging/"
        break;
      case "staging":
        accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_STAGING;
        accessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_STAGING;
        bucketName = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STAGING;
        bucketFolder="staging/"
        break;
      case "production":
        accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PRODUCTION;
        accessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PRODUCTION;
        bucketName = process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_PRODUCTION;
        bucketFolder="production/"
        break;
    }
const s3 = new aws.S3();

/*******************************************************/
// Uploading File to S3 Bucket.
/*******************************************************/
let storage = multerS3({
  s3: s3,
  bucket: bucketName,
  key: async (req, file, cb) => {
    if (String(req.url) === "/add/admin" || req.url.includes("update/admin")) {
      folderName = bucketFolder+`uploads/admin/profilePictures`;
      imagePath = folderName + "/" + Date.now() + "." + mime.extension(file.mimetype);

    }
    if (String(req.url) === "/add/branch" || req.url.includes("update/branch")) {
      folderName = bucketFolder+`uploads/branch/logos`;
      imagePath = folderName + "/" + Date.now() + "." + mime.extension(file.mimetype);
    }
    if (String(req.url) === "/add/staff-member" || req.url.includes("update/staff-member")) {
      folderName = bucketFolder+`uploads/staff/profilePictures`;
      imagePath = folderName + "/" + Date.now() + "." + mime.extension(file.mimetype);
    }
    if (String(req.url) === "/add/child" || req.url.includes("update/child")) {
      folderName = bucketFolder+`uploads/child/pictures`;
      imagePath = folderName + "/" + Date.now() + "." + mime.extension(file.mimetype);
    }

    fs.mkdirsSync(folderName);
    cb(null, imagePath);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + "." + mime.extension(file.mimetype));
  }
});
```

Comment: Presumably `bucketName` is null

Comment: have you solved this issue??? @usman khalid